# Storing in BLOB- only 1 KB of data, No image stored

Tags: php, android, mysql, file, encode

I have encoded an image to base 64 as

```
        Bitmap bitmapOrg= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte [] byarray = bao.toByteArray();
        String myimage=Base64.encodeBytes(byarray);
```

.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new
    HttpPost("http://10.1.1.5/connect/royal.php");

    try{
        List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IMAGE",myimage));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FILENAME",trID));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("chddeck", responseStr);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseStr);
        int success = jsonObj.getInt("success");
        if (success == 1) {
            status="1";
        }else if (success==0){
            status="0";
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
```

in php, I have stored as:

```
$base = $_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
$buffer=base64_decode($base);
$path = "upload/".$filename.".jpg";
$handle = fopen($path, 'wb');
$numbytes = fwrite($handle, $buffer);
fclose($handle);

$query = $link->prepare("UPDATE transaction evidenceimage=?,evidencename=? WHERE transactionID =   '5'");
        $values = array($path, $filename);
        $query->execute($values);   
        $counts= $query->rowCount();
                if ($counts>0)
                {
                    $rowset = $query->fetchAll();
                    $response["comments"]=array();
                    $comments =array();
                    $response["success"]=1;
                }
                else{
                $response["success"]=0;
                }
echo json_encode($response);
```

Problem is, image is perfectly uploaded in the "upload/" directory in server. But not stored in mysql. In mysql - evidenceimage is set to be "BLOB. After this query, "BLOB-filenameB" is stored in the table, which appears to be only 1 KB.
Please could anybody suggest what am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

To get the image in your android program I think you need to pass the path of image uploaded in your localhost or the server. And to get the image at your application try this:

```
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable("your imageview name",
                    "your image path in localhost or server", 
                    "optional image to display if not available in your drawable folder",
                    "cache duration");
```

you can get the library UrlImageViewHelper here:
http://www.koushikdutta.com/UrlImageViewHelper